# with this htaccess setting I cannot connect with my site

Tags: php, .htaccess

My problem is that I had an online site that was made to me. now I have downloaded the site locally on my wamp because I would like to make some changes.
the site is under a folder called auctions. So the index.php is found under wamp64 / www / auctions / index.php
All this to tell you that if I go to the browser's localhost I can't get to the login page, I always go into error and the only thing I understand is that the problem is htaccess.
I attach a link to github to take a part of the site if someone can understand the problem.

https://github.com/CP1975/htaccess

Wamp mod_rewrite is enabled.

I digit http://localhost/aste and with this htaccess code:

`Options -Indexes

#BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
#END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

#add a trailing slash to /ios-admin
RewriteRule ^ios-admin$ ios-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(ios-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpeg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/gif
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

##EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
##EXPIRES CACHING ##

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>`

the system go to the follow url:

http://localhost/en/login

and I received this error:

**Not Found.

The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) PHP/7.3.21 Server at localhost Port 80**

thank you
Charles

Comment: Please read [ask]. Include the pertinent information *in the question itself* (not as a link to an external site). "I always go into error" isn't a helpful description of the problem, at least tell us what the error message is!

Comment: Please add the exact error message you get and the relevant contents of your http server's error log file into the question itself, along with the content of the htaccess file itself.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I added the exact error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem summary

- You visit this URL: `http://localhost/aste`
- The system forwards you to: `http://localhost/en/login`
- You get an error /en/login cannot be found

### Possible solutions

You can probably tell it should be `http://localhost/aste/en/login`

Either of these should work. Can't help you with all of them:

- You move all files up one folder.. probably the easiest if this is your only web project.
- Configure the base path to prepend `/aste` (if you know where that can be configured)
- Configure your system to use a subdomain, for example `aste.localhost` which Apache forwards to the `/aste` directory. That's a bit of work but is very good if you plan to have several web-projects on your machine.

Comment: with this doesn't function...http://localhost/aste/en/login and for your other suggestions I can't reply them. Can you try to ue my file in github? probably you can understand quickly? thank you